# How to refresh a lock screen appwidget when the device wakes up

Tags: android, android-appwidget, lockscreen

When an appwidget is displayed on the Android 4.2 lock screen, how can it be refreshed with new data when the user presses the power button to wake up the device from sleep?

It appears that none of the callbacks in the AppWidgetProvider class are called at that time.

The refresh on wakeup is needed if auto-rotate screen is enabled, because when the device is rotated while the lock screen is displayed, then goes to sleep, after the device is awakened the widget no longer shows the data it displayed prior to the device going to sleep.